# How can I inject Optional<T> with hk2?

Tags: dependency-injection, jersey, guice, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have a Factory that looks at some property to determine if the value T should be provided. How can I use this with HK2 in an abstract binder?

```
public interface Printer {
    void print(String str);
}

public ConsolePrinter implements Printer {

    public void print(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

public PrinterFactory implements Factory<Optional<Printer>> {
    
    boolean isPrinterAvailable;

    public PrinterFactory(boolean isPrinterAvailable) {
        this.isPrinterAvailable = isPrinterAvailable;
    }

    public Optional<Printer> provide() {
        if (this.isPrinterAvailable) {
            return new ConsolePrinter();
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}


public class Binder extends AbstractBinder {
    protected void configure() {
        // ?????
        bindFactory(PrinterFactory.class).to(Printer.class);
    }
}
```

Any help/documentation/examples is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to bind to `new TypeLiteral<O<P>>(){}`

Comment: Please check the documentation: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings#optionalbinder